# Statsmodel: how to create a custom formula with transformations on the xs, without putting X,Y on the logit function?

Tags: python, statsmodels

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R59i1.png)

```
formula = "y~np.log(x1)+ x2 +x3+\
           x4+x5)"
```

This situation throws out the

```
error  __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'exog'
```

because it generally takes X and Y as parameters. But on the documentation, I see another solution results possible: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/example_formulas.html

With transformations, I mean something like a quadratic, cubic function of my variables.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
```

and so changing the code for the model

glmfinal=**smf.glm**(formula=formula, family=sm.families.Binomial(), data=Noinflu_df).fit()